# Storing a tree structure in java

Tags: java

I want to pre-compute some moves for my Game AI and store them on the disk, to be loaded at runtime.
The moves are stored in a quinary tree and I'd appreciate it if you could recommend me some libraries that could let me to easily save them and restore them.

Comment: Won't object file do it? You can serialize you tree and store it in bin file.

Comment: Well, it depends on what plataform are you working. J2ME (mobile devices), J2EE (Portable Applications), J2SE (Server Programming), JavaFX (Internet Applications)

Comment: @Eder: Umm, I think you need to look at what the different flavors of Java mean...

Answer (score 3):

Use Java's serialization mechanism for persisting your tree, is the simplest solution, and use ObjectInputStream for reading / ObjectOutputStream for writing the serialized data from/to disk.

Comment: Isn't this slightly inefficient for large amounts of data?

Comment: It depends :) on how large is the data set, and on your definition of efficiency. Given that the serialization mechanism is built into the language, it must be quite efficient - probably not as efficient as designing your own serialization scheme, but you still have a good amount of control over how the serialization works and what gets serialized - see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answers, you can make your tree implement the `Serializable` and let the JVM do everything for you (make sure all node classes are Serializable as well)

```
public class Tree implements Serializable{
   Node rootNode = ...

}
```

If your tree contains a large amount of data then you could probably trim down all the data that can be re-calculated when the tree is reloaded from disk, have a look at the [Momento design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) to get an idea on how this can be acheived.